# Provisioning Profiles Not Found inside xamarin studio

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, mobile, xamarin

I Have prblem in my app ios I need Publish this App to my Iphone Device and

I connect my Iphone to Mac and create Provisioning Profiles by Xcode and Provisioning showing in Account Xcode like this Image

[image]
but when go to my app in site xamarin I don't found Provisioning Profiles and result like this image

[image]
please help my

Comment: did you specified bundle identifier in project settings?

Answer (score 4):

There are two things to check here:

1. Does your bundle ID in your app's Info.plist file match the app ID linked to the provisioning profile in your Apple developer account? Xamarin Studio will only show provisioning profiles that are relevant to your bundle ID.
2. Do you have the certificate that your provisioning profile is linked to installed on your Mac? If you do, is it up to date? For instance, if you recreated your certificate and provisioning profiles in your Apple developer account but didn't install the new certificate on your Mac, XCode will show your provisioning profiles as downloaded, but Xamarin Studio will not show them without the relevant certificate.

Comment: I have this problem too. I tried the two steps you proposed. All certificates and provisioning profiles are installed correctly on the Mac. I can build in XCode with the same Bundle Id with Xamarin.iOS'. But when I try to choose the relevant provisioning profile for Release version in VS(both Windows and Mac), I cannot see it. "No matching profiles found" error only I see.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Go to Xcode, create a new project. Select your company name(do not select user), then type in anything you want as your bundle identifier.
2. Go back to Xamarin studio and change the bundle identifier to match the one you just created in Xcode.
3. Update the provisioning profile in options to include the bundle identifier you created in Xcode. Build, then Debug the solution and it should work.

For me the issue was the team identifier contained the only provisions, and the only selection in Xamarin studio were users. I just created a new project in Xcode that pointed to the team provision, then used that new bundle identifier (that was uploaded to the Apple dev site) in Xamarin studio.